# Hook into a Wordpress plugin, get product information and change the behavior

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, hook

I have this Woocommerce Invoicing plugin which has in itself a field called "product summary". This field does not exist in Woocommerce by default and is not mapped, however It has the following code that allows to hook and define what the product summary should be

```
    /**
 * @param null|string $summary
 * @return $this
 */
public function setSummary($summary = null)
{
    $summary = apply_filters('moloni_before_order_item_setSummary', $summary, $this->product);

    if ($summary) {
        $this->summary = $summary;
    } else {
        $this->summary .= $this->getSummaryVariationAttributes();

        if (!empty($this->summary)) {
            $this->summary .= "\n";
        }

        $this->summary .= $this->getSummaryExtraProductOptions();
    }

    $this->summary = apply_filters('moloni_after_order_item_setSummary', $summary, $this->product);

    return $this;
}
```

From here I am trying to define the Product Short Description field as the Summary, however I am not sure what is the correct way to do this but so far I have come up to this (which I can't get to work):

```
/** Moloni Product Summary hook and get product shot description */

add_filter( 'moloni_before_order_item_setSummary', 'summary_is_exerpt', 10, 1 );

function summary_is_exerpt ( $summary , $product ) {
global $product;
        // Get the product object for this ID:

        $product->get_id();

       // Get product short description

          $summary = $product->get_short_description();
        

return $summary;

    }
```

I always get an error like:
**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id() on null in**

I assume that $product is not defined.I  have tried to set global variables like:
global $product;
global $woocommerce, $post;

However without success, the error remains.

Does this approach make sense? Can anyone shine me some light in the right direction?
Thank you in advance for the attention and advice.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried updating the `$accepted_args` to `2`?  and or a later `priority`?

```
<?php

// use later pri and update to 2 accepted args
add_filter( 'moloni_before_order_item_setSummary', 'summary_is_exerpt', 20, 2 );

// remove setting global product
function summary_is_exerpt ( $summary , $product ) {
    // Get the product object for this ID
    $product->get_id();

    // Get product short description
    $summary = 'TESTE RESUMO';

    return $summary;
}
```

Comment: By mistake I had shared an older version of the code up here on the post and I just updated it. 

Your suggestion makes sense, I was not aware of this and I already learned something!

However after updating it this way I am still receiving the error 
"PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id() on null " 

It seems its still not receiving the $product variable info